# Angular 6 testing mock dependency from class

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I am new to Angular and I have started to write my first test. Could someone help me understand how the dependency injection works ?

I have a class called Level.ts which looks something like this:

```
export class Level {
 Title: string,
 isTitle: boolean
}
```

and my actual component called Previewer.component.ts which looks like

```
import { Input,Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Level} from '../Level';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-previewer',
  templateUrl: './previewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./previewer.component.css']
})
export class Previewer implements OnInit {
  @Input() level: Level;

confirmTitle(){
 this.level.Title = "Level 1";
 this.level.isTitle = true;
}
}
```

I must add that I am not using a service currently and would want to test the previewer.component.ts file. However when I run the test, it throws an error saying that 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'isTitle' of undefined'. I have also used the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, but still I get this error thown.
Kindly help

I am setting the level property in my test file

```
describe('PreviewerComponent', () => {
  let component: PreviewerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PreviewerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ PreviewerComponent ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(VideoImageTextPreviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    **component.step.HasVideo = false;**
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

My HTML file looks like this

```
<div class="levelPreviewWindow">
                    <div class="mediaBackground" *ngIf="level.isTitle">
                        <video [src]="level.Title" preload="auto" *ngIf="level.isTitle" autoplay controls loop>
                            <source type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="!level.isTitle">
                        <input type="file" class="mediaUploader" (change)="PreviewVideo($event)">
                    </div>    
                </div>
```

Comment: In your test, you need to make sure you set the `level` property, otherwise it will be undefined. Alternately, in your component, you need to add some `null` / `undefined` checks

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, when I set the level property i.e. level.isTitle in the above example, I get an error stating that 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'isTitle' of undefined'.

Comment: You need to make sure you set `level` before you can set `level.isTitle`. Can you please update the question to show how you're setting it?

Comment: I have edited it above

Comment: I can't see that you're setting it anywhere? Just do `component.level = new Level()` in your `beforeEach`

Comment: I did as per your recommendation. I think that the error is thrown because of my HTML file. I have updated the HTML file above. Despite me using NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, I am getting the error

Comment: Okay, then on your top level div there, just add `*ngIf="level"`, so that it only tries to render when level has already been set

Comment: It's working now. Thank you soooo much for your help :D My test cases are also running fine now :D